# Click Function Bound to Button Type=Submit is Called on "Enter" Key Press

Tags: jquery

I have a form button that has the type="submit" attribute.

I then have some jquery code adding some functionality when the button is clicked.

This code in the click() function is called if the form is submitted using the "Enter" button on the keyboard.

Is this normal?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. Also, for future reference, showing us the code instead of describing it makes a question much clearer.

Comment: Thank you! Just wanted to make sure I didn't also code a keypress function causing the same code to be called twice. Also wanted to make sure this wasn't some bug I was experiencing and is consistent across all browsers.

Comment: No problem. If you're that concerned, I'd suggest hooking the event to the `submit` event of the `form` instead of the `click` of the `button`. That way it doesn't matter how the user submits the form

Comment: That is what I was initially doing, but for some reason Leadpages won't call the code before the form actually submits and redirects the user :/

Answer (score 0):

Rory McCrossan answered the question and confirmed this is normal functionality.

Thank you.